# Fill between behind the axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to fill in the region bounded by the coordinate axes and the 1st-quadrant portion of the hyperbola $xy=1$. But the region just obscures my x-axis (and the y-axis closed to origin). Is there anyway to fix this? Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{figure}
\centering{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    axis lines = middle,
    x label style={at={(axis cs:4,0)}, anchor=west},
    y label style={at={(axis cs:0,4)}, anchor=south},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, ticks=none,
    xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,},
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1, unbounded coords=jump]
        \addplot[name path = a, domain=0.1:4] ({x},{1/x});
        \path[name path=paxis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:4,0);
        \addplot[yellow] fill between[of=a and paxis];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's probably a better way, but you could create additional paths (named `aa` and `bb`) for the unbounded portion. Note also the use of `axis on top`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=-4, xmax=4, ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    axis on top,
    axis lines = middle,
    x label style={at={(axis cs:4,0)}, anchor=west},
    y label style={at={(axis cs:0,4)}, anchor=south},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, ticks=none,
    xticklabels={,,}, yticklabels={,,},
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1, unbounded coords=jump]
        \addplot[name path = a, domain=0.25:4] ({x},{1/x});
        \path[name path=paxis] (axis cs:.25,0) -- (axis cs:4,0);
        \path[name path=aa] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:.25,0);
        \path[name path=bb] (axis cs:0,4) -- (axis cs:.25,4);
        \addplot[yellow] fill between[of=a and paxis];
        \addplot[yellow] fill between[of=aa and bb];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another possibilities is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = middle,
    axis on top,
    xmin=-4, xmax=4, 
    ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    x label style={anchor=west},
    y label style={anchor=south},
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, 
    ticks=none,
    domain=0.1:4
            ]
\addplot[draw=none, fill=yellow] {1/x} |- (0,0) -- (0,4);
\addplot[thick] {1/x};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, in axis preamble is considered syntax of ˙pgfplots` after version 1.11-